# Custom SQL Query to HTML

Tags: sql-server

I have been doing a lot of research and everything I find is using PHP and MySQL. I need to be able to access my ODBC SQL Server (my MRP system) and display a custom query on a webpage for a visual for my plant. I have not been able to find a way to establish a connection to the database nor the correct way to format the query to display data. Any and all recommendations and formatting corrections are greatly appreciated. I am not even sure HTML is the route I need to go. I just need to build a table based on this data with further ability to format using specific string values from the table.

**The query is below:**

```
with cte as
(
SELECT DISTINCT
orout.PartNo,
sched.JobNo,
sched.StepNo,
orout.DeptNum AS MachCell,
orout.WorkCntr as Descrip,
agg.sumHours as HrsLeft,
agg.sumManHrs,
agg.minStartDate,
agg.maxEndDate,
sched.Priority,
od.QtyToMake,
isnull(tt2.QtyComplete,0) as QtyComplete,
CASE
WHEN isnull(tt2.QtyComplete,0) = 0 THEN od.QtyToMake
ELSE (od.QtyToMake - tt2.QtyComplete)
END as QtyOpen,
orout.TotActHrs,
orout.TotEstHrs,
emp.EmplCode,
Emp.NewEmplShortName,
emp.WorkCntr,
wc.Descrip as wcDescrip,
CASE
WHEN emp.EmplCode IS NOT null THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS LoginPriority



FROM Scheduling as sched

LEFT JOIN OrderRouting as orout
ON orout.JobNo = sched.JobNo AND orout.StepNo = sched.StepNo

LEFT JOIN OrderDet as od
ON orout.JobNo = od.JobNo

LEFT JOIN
    (   
        SELECT
            JobNo,
            online.EmplCode,
            EmplCode.NewEmplShortName,
            WorkCntr,
            StepNo
        FROM Online
        INNER JOIN EmplCode
        ON EmplCode.EmplCode = online.EmplCode
    ) emp
ON emp.JobNo = orout.JobNo and emp.StepNo = orout.StepNo

LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            JobNo,
            StepNo,
            SUM(ManHrs) as sumManHrs,
            SUM(Hours) as sumHours,
            MIN(StartDate) as minStartDate,
            MAX(EndDate) as maxEndDate
        FROM
        Scheduling
        GROUP BY JobNo, StepNo
    ) agg
    ON agg.JobNo = sched.JobNo AND agg.StepNo = sched.StepNo

LEFT JOIN TimeTicketDet as tt
ON tt.JobNo = orout.JobNo and tt.StepNo = orout.StepNo

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            JobNo,
            StepNo,
            SUM(PiecesFinished+PiecesScrapped) as QtyComplete
        FROM
        TimeTicketDet as tt2
        GROUP BY JobNo, StepNo
    ) tt2
ON tt2.JobNo = orout.JobNo and tt2.StepNo = tt.StepNo

LEFT JOIN WorkCntr as wc
ON emp.WorkCntr = wc.WorkCntr

WHERE
sched.Priority > 0

)

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE 
Descrip = 'MACHINE2'
ORDER BY
LoginPriority DESC, Priority DESC, minStartDate
```

Comment: What web technologies are you familiar with?  Have you got existing web applications up and running at your place?

Comment: you need to write some code to perform the query and return the data you've only provided the query here. Once you've done that then you can worry about processing it into html

Comment: @evilbhonda Honestly none, I am open to learning everything I need to learn. I just need to be able to present that to the directors. I basically only know SQL and slight python.

Comment: I feel your pain but this is just way too big of a topic. You are asking us to provide with a set of instructions for building a website. Try using a search engine, you will find thousands and thousands of examples.

Comment: I suggest hiring a developer. You don't want to build programs that become a nightmare to manage in a few years for your successor. Option 2 if you insist, if you are a Microsoft shop, try WebMatrix from Microsoft. They have a few starter kits that you can possibly use

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking for an off-the-shelf application that can use a SQL view as a data source.  You can then write a view in SQL to return the data you need displaying, then leave the application to handle everything in the UI.

I've not used any in-depth, and I'm not affiliated with any, but the two I've played with in the past are https://www.tableau.com/ and https://powerbi.microsoft.com.  Tableau more of a dashboard tool (and maybe a bit pricey), but I think PowerBI is free, but they're just examples of something you can use.  Have a look around, but you should be able to find something that you can use.